# Difference between Normative annexes and Informative annexes in ADA 95

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, books

I was reading the ADA 95 reference manual. I came across these  two words in annexes 
 Normative and informative . I couldnt find the difference between those. Your help will  be much appreciated.

Comment: This is completely covered by the Wikipedia entry for [Normative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normative#Standards_documents) (which was essentially the same when the question was asked as it is today).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Normative" means something that has to be followed, part of the standard. "Informative" is explanations meant to be understood by mere human beings, and that might be ambiguous or inaccurate. It is *not* to be relied on. Read it to understand, refer to the normative parts where it matters.

Answer (score -1):

"Informative" annexes are a clever way to add requirements and details originally missed or poorly defined by the standard developers.  These "corrections" are largely due to the developers academic bias and the general lack of real world experiencing producing actual product.  But make no mistake, you'll be expected to meet informative annex content just as if it were in the body.

Comment: [Citation needed]. This directly contradicts the accepted answer and the Wikipedia page and mostly seems to be a rant against academia.

Answer (score -5):

Normative is it is and informative is it could be.  One is certainly settled while the other is yet settled.

Comment: Please take a look at vonbrand's answer. What you have described is a "working draft", not answer to given question (it is incorrect). Informative is supplemental information to normative part - which is standard to comply with.

Comment: I find this answer very hard to follow. And I'm not convinced it's correct: "informative" parts of a standard are not necessarily things that haven't been settled; rather, they're things that are relevant to the standard but not necessarily part of it.